# Получение/отправка в input VUE.js

Tags: vue.js

Подскажите пожалуйста, как на vue в инпуте сначала получить данные при открытии окна, а потом, отредактировав значение инпута, отправить новые данные.

Comment: Необходимо в компоненте создать переменную под каждый инпут. Затем инпут со своей переменной должны быть связаны двусторонней связью: v-bind делает инпут зависимым от значения переменной, а обработка события ввода должна обновлять саму переменную новым значением.

Comment: Когда переменные связаны со своими элементами ввода, можно вводить данные прямо в переменные и читать прямо из переменных.

Comment: Почитайте документацию по v-bind, обработке событий, а также по v-model, который является сочетанием предыдущих двух тем

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать директиву `v-model` для двунаправленного связывания данных с элементами форм `input`, `textarea` и `select`.

```html
<input v-model="message" placeholder="отредактируй меня">
<p>Введённое сообщение: {{ message }}</p>
```